# Doesn't an Abstract Factory class break the life cycle management of an IoC Container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, containers

```cs
public class MyClassFactory : IMyClassFactory
{ 
    private readonly IMySingleton _mySingleton;
    private readonly IMyNonSingleton _myNonSingleton;

    public MyClassFactory(
        IMySingleton mySingleton, 
        IMyNonSingleton myNonSingleton
        )
    {
        _mySingleton = mySingleton;
        _myNonSingleton = myNonSingleton;
    }

    public IMyResult CreateMyResult(int resultId)
    {
        // right here - have i not arbitrarily extended the lifespan
        //              of _myNonSingleton?  
        //
        return new MyResult(_mySingleton, _myNonSingleton, resultId);
    }
}
```

With this setup, every new MyResult will get the same instance of IMyNonSingleton.  Isn't the only way to solve this problem is to call Resolve on the container again every time you create a MyResult?

As well, if I do that, doesn't that start looking like a Service Locator pattern?  At minimum, I'll be violating rules like "Don't call the container, it'll call you" and "you only call Resolve once" correct?

EDIT: The idea here is that IMySingleton has been registered in my container as a singleton and the other classes have not.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call those `singletons`, but rather something like context instances. There's nothing "singleton" about them.

Comment: @TyCobb - Sorry, by the looks of it, I can see how I didn't paint a very clear picture here.  The connotation is that IMySingleton has been registered in my container as a singleton and the other classes have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *potential* to extend lifetime of objects inadvertently, but it applies to all cases where lifetime of one object does not match lifetime of other.

Cases when it may not be a problem:

- you may be asking container for the factory every time you need one or lifetime of the factory matches the shortest lifetime of objects that are used by the factory.
- you actually need objects to have longer lifetime (or matching to factory)
- objects with shorter lifetime don't care

Cases when it may be a problem:

- your factory has longer lifetime (i.e. application), but objects must be created every time or at some other frequency managed by IOC container.

Workarounds:

- integrate factory with container (i.e. pass container to factory and use its resolve methods to construct inner objects)
- pass "creator" methods instead of instances into constructor to avoid direct dependency on container.
- forgo factory altogether and integrate it directly into container initialization.

I.e. Microsoft Unity container registers both type and `Func<T>`, so your factory can immediately take dependency on creator functions like:

```
 public MyClassFactory(
    Func<IMySingleton> mySingleton, 
    Func<IMyNonSingleton> myNonSingleton
    )...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My current workaround is your first suggestion.  It seems that if you are always asking the container for your things, you can never shoot yourself in the foot.  For me, the many calls to resolve are starting to "feel" wrong.

Comment: +1.  I would add: strive to design your components so they will function properly regardless of how they are scoped in the container.  Most components that are modeled as pure services can be scoped as singleton or transient and work identically.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you can change interface of IMyClassFactory to

```
public interface IMyClassFactory
{
    IMyResult CreateMyResult(int resultId, IMyNonSingleton myNonSinglrton);
}
```

2) Or you need a IMyNonSingletonFactory to rewrite code like this

```
public class MyClassFactory : IMyClassFactory
{ 
    private readonly IMySingleton _mySingleton;
    private readonly IMyNonSingletonFactory _myNonSingletonFactory;

    public MyClassFactory(
        IMySingleton mySingleton, 
        IMyNonSingletonFactory myNonSingletonFactory
    )
    {
        _mySingleton = mySingleton;
        _myNonSingletonFactory = myNonSingletonFactory;
    }

    public IMyResult CreateMyResult(int resultId)
    {
        //you need your definition of INonSingletonFactory
        return new MyResult(_mySingleton, _myNonSingletonFactory.Create(), resultId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for responding.  I see your point here.  I think the other part of my problem is that my code ends up looking like factory central.  Every time I make a class that can't be resolved, I have to make another class factory for it.  This happens a lot in particular on our UI side, all of it starts to feel fairly tedious and distracting.   We keep doing it, I guess, for the usual IoC/DI benefits, but it continues to be distracting.